# How to create a HelloWorld JAX-WS example (client - service)?

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, webservice-client

I'm really new in Java Web Service. I can say that my knowledge level is only 10%. Can somebody please give me a HelloWorld Example of JAX-WS (client - service) with explanations?...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a common question and perhaps a duplicate one too. But I would like to provide some links which might get you started.

1. This [mkyong blog](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/) has good explanation with all the necessary examples.
2. Another [blog](http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/jaxwscxf_step2/) which has provided two different articles for setting up the server and accessing it with the client.

You can also search it in google and get plenty of references to look. 
Hope it will help you get started.

**EDIT:**

Another [Dzone article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world) that also has provided an example. 
All these examples are JAX-WS.

Answer (score 1):

Or oracle tutorial:

[Creating a Simple Web Service and Client with JAX-WS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)