# JAX-WS webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new to web service programming. I have created one JAX-WS SOAP web service and deployed it locally. I am writing client in java to invoke the service. Basically, this service takes two integers and returns the sum of them. I have written the following [JAX-WS client](http://www.tutorialscorner.com/webservice/JAX-WS-Client.html) in java.

```
public class WebserviceClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL
                ("http://localhost:9999/ws/additionService?wsdl");

        QName qname = new QName("http://test/", 
                "AdditionServiceImplService");

        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        AdditionService additionService = service
                .getPort(AdditionService.class);

        System.out.println(additionService.add(1, 2));
```

The above code is working fine. But, in this code I need to create `QName` by passing the targetNamespace and name of the service. I want to know whether constructing `QName` is mandatory? Since, I am already passing the WSDL URL, no point creating `QName` with the WSDL `targetnamespace` string. Is there any alternative approach available?

Comment: What is package name where this class is located ?

Comment: You may find some usefull links for alternative ways of creating web service clients in the answers of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537236/how-to-create-a-helloworld-jax-ws-example-client-service) stackoverflow question.