# How to specify wsdlLocation for local file

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I am new to the game of web-service clients, and have generated code using the wsdl2java maven dependency.

**I am packaging this project as a .war file.**

My issue is that I do not know how to make the autogenerated client reach an endpoint across domains, and I also do not know how to set the client's wsdlLocation properly.

**Starting with the latter:**
Inside of the autogenerated service class, I found a `static URL WSDL_LOCATION` attribute, as well as 'parameters?' to a WebServiceClient annotation.

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "my_service", 
                  wsdlLocation = "file:/c:/tmp/my_service.wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "someAutoGenTargetNS/wsdl") 
public class my_service_Service extends Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("someAutoGenTargetNS/wsdl", "my_service");
    public final static QName my_service = new QName("http://someAtuoGenTargetNS/wsdl", "my_service");
    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("file:/c:/tmp/my_service.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(my_service_Service.class.getName())
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                     "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "file:/c:/tmp/my_service.wsdl");
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }
```

Currently, the WSDL_LOCATION url is always set to null, as it can not find the filepath specified (which is expected). I have the wsdl and xsd stored in the resources folder, but do not know how to specify the path to reach that. I have tried

```
new URL("file:/resources/my_service.wsdl")
new URL("file:/src/main/java/resources/my_service.wsdl")
new URL("classpath:my_service.wsdl")
```

and quite a few others. What is the correct way to do this, and if it requires an xml-catalog, where can I find documentation about where to put the catalog.xml file.

**And now the former:**
I believe my implementation to change the endpoint to the location I want is correct, and it is the wsdlLocation issue that is giving me a headache. Here is my implementation to change the endpoints. If this does not look right, simply point me in the direction of what to use, no need for a full implementation.

```
private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName(""someAutoGenTargetNS/wsdl"", "my_service");
    private URL wsdlURL = my_service_Service.WSDL_LOCATION;
    my_service_Service ss;
    my_service port;
public my_service_client()
{
        //Redacted code for trusting all SSL Certs and hostnameVerifiers as it is not needed for the scope of this question
        this.ss = new my_service_Service(this.wsdlURL,SERVICE_NAME);
        this.port = ss.getMy_Service();
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) this.port;
        Map<String,Object> clientRequestContext = bp.getRequestContext();
        clientRequestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://New_Endpoint_IP");
//Basic auth header credentials
        clientRequestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,"username");
        clientRequestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,"password");
}
```

Resources I attempted to understand prior to asking this question:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163586/jax-ws-client-whats-the-correct-path-to-access-the-local-wsdl)
[2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/xml.html)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455195/how-to-avoid-the-need-to-specify-the-wsdl-location-in-a-cxf-or-jax-ws-generated)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764772/jax-ws-loading-wsdl-from-jar)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java)
[6](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jaxws002.html)
[7+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537236/how-to-create-a-helloworld-jax-ws-example-client-service)
[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490737/how-to-change-webservice-url-endpoint)

Conclusively, I am coming to the realization I would much rather work with HTTP than SOAP, but legacy systems require legacy interaction.

Error's received that lead me to believe this is a wsdlURL issue:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Internal Error (from client)
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Internal Error (from client)
```

Comment: Can i see how you are instantiating the Service?

Comment: @EmanuelRamirez Thank you for coming to my aid, but you were roughly 5 minutes too late to the party! So happy to finally have figured out my error, even though it appeared to not be related to what I posted at all.

Comment: Haha i'm glad its solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue (4 days of tracking the problem later, and i can solve it shortly after asking the question here...)

This is indeed a valid way of setting the endpoint URL. That answers that question.

I adopted the `classLoader.getResource` approach from this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455195/how-to-avoid-the-need-to-specify-the-wsdl-location-in-a-cxf-or-jax-ws-generated) to set the wsdlLocation

My new code became:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "my_service", 
                  wsdlLocation = "classpath:my_service.wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "someAutoGenTargetNS/wsdl") 
public class my_service_Service extends Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("someAutoGenTargetNS/wsdl", "my_service");
    public final static QName my_service = new QName("http://someAtuoGenTargetNS/wsdl", "my_service");
    static {
        URL url = null;
            url = my_service.class.getClassLoader().getResource("my_service.wsdl");
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }
```

Lastly I realized that the most basic web-service call I was trying to utilize was incorrectly setting the request body. I had set the request_body to null, in stead of instantiation a new instance of the request class that was autogenerated. This is what was throwing these two errors, but I am sure fixing the above helped lead me to the solution by enforcing my understanding of how these pieces work together.